# Application testing by apple store on iPad 3 iOS 5.1.1 crash issue

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipod

Apple store suggested, **We found that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 5.1.1**, With below mentioned reason,

**Reason:**

```
Incident Identifier: 9C3164B4-AD47-41DB-AA66-6786ED699A5D
CrashReporter Key:   a718036fcb264850c199f1bafc4de94bdc6c5234
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         Password [3188]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/91AFA46A-8BF8-4EE3-83D2-5E4DDD87F602/Password.app/Password
Identifier:      Password
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-05 16:59:23.579 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xf64cb580
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Password                        0x0000bdb8 0x1000 + 44472
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4facc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4f32e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 358
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4e03e __CFRunLoopRun + 646
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32ad149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32ad1366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   GraphicsServices                0x32c1e432 GSEventRunModal + 130
7   UIKit                           0x350b0cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
8   Password                        0x000029f6 0x1000 + 6646
9   Password                        0x0000298c 0x1000 + 6540

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x350423a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a6f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a6c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x350520d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f2d674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   WebCore                         0x357cc4e8 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208
3   WebCore                         0x357cc7ec _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 24
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4fb14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4dd50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
6   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4e16a __CFRunLoopRun + 946
7   CoreFoundation                  0x32ad149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
8   CoreFoundation                  0x32ad1366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
9   WebCore                         0x3586fc9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f3972e _pthread_start + 314
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f395e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.SystemConfiguration.SCNetworkReachability.xpcq
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35042054 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a74ee _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$mp + 6
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a69b0 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 68
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a58b4 _dispatch_sync_f2 + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a5282 dispatch_sync_f$VARIANT$mp + 46
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a52e4 dispatch_get_specific$VARIANT$mp + 52
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x30507694 _xpc_connection_reply_cancel + 48
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a8236 _dispatch_source_invoke + 346
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a5b7a _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 46
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x312a5c9e _dispatch_queue_drain + 162
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x312a5b6e _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x312a5c9e _dispatch_queue_drain + 162
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x312a5b6e _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x312a67e0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 204
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f33df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f33cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35042004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x350421fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4f3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32b4e124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32ad149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32ad1366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x371cfbb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x371cfa7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3726358a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f3972e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f395e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35052570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32b5363a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f3972e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f395e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35052cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f33f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f33cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35052cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f33f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31f33cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001ce810    r1: 0x00000002      r2: 0x00198620      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x001ce810    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x0000bdba      r7: 0x2fdfef38
    r8: 0x00198620    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x36c95b53     r11: 0x36c95b53
    ip: 0x001ce828    sp: 0x2fdfec9c      lr: 0x36c7bceb      pc: 0x0000bdb8
  cpsr: 0x600f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x5dfff +Password armv7  <ec69f90aa79e306fb62f0008879887ba> /var/mobile/Applications/91AFA46A-8BF8-4EE3-83D2-5E4DDD87F602/Password.app/Password
0x2fe62000 - 0x2fe83e17  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3018c000 - 0x30197ff7  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x302e5000 - 0x3032afff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x3032b000 - 0x3039bffb  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x303b5000 - 0x30484fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <49607ffe4ee9389494285a213e392924> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30485000 - 0x30486ffd  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30493000 - 0x304f0fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x304f1000 - 0x304f1fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30504000 - 0x30515ff4  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3052e000 - 0x305adffd  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x305ae000 - 0x305e5fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30740000 - 0x3077cff7  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x30786000 - 0x3078cfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3078d000 - 0x3078dffe  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3079b000 - 0x30941eef  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x30944000 - 0x30a4affb  IMGSGX543GLDriver armv7  <7454a840600038949d67edad05097242> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX543GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX543GLDriver
0x30aad000 - 0x30abcffc  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x30abd000 - 0x30ad1ffb  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x30afa000 - 0x30b6eff7  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x30b6f000 - 0x30b73fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30c8e000 - 0x30ccaff7  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x30ccb000 - 0x30d00ffe  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x30d01000 - 0x30d02fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x30f26000 - 0x30f7effb  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30f7f000 - 0x30f8eff2  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x311f8000 - 0x31210fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31211000 - 0x31213ffe  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x312a3000 - 0x312b9fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x312ee000 - 0x312f2ffd  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x312f3000 - 0x31318ff9  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x31349000 - 0x3134afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31386000 - 0x31448ffb  Celestial armv7  <19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x314bc000 - 0x314d9ff7  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x314da000 - 0x314ebfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31995000 - 0x31995fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31d19000 - 0x31d1bffd  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x31d1e000 - 0x31d1efff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x31d1f000 - 0x31d22ffe  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31d23000 - 0x31d36fff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <3f4596cbe1b13fdcb427d87de21df3f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x31d3a000 - 0x31d51fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <696bb0630b19388da0d72e685bcf6e28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x31da9000 - 0x31dbffff  VoiceServices armv7  <c5b98e94eff33bf49006ff157c819987> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x31dc0000 - 0x31dc7fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x31dc8000 - 0x31dcdff7  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31edd000 - 0x31f27ff9  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31f2b000 - 0x31fb7ff3  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x31fb8000 - 0x31fbafff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <808518e0fbf539af8489f028ca5198c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x31fbb000 - 0x31fbcfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31fc4000 - 0x320b5ff3  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x322da000 - 0x32387ff7  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x32388000 - 0x32389fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x323c1000 - 0x323c1ffd  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x32657000 - 0x326a1ff3  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32700000 - 0x32704fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x32708000 - 0x3278effc  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x3278f000 - 0x3287dffa  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32886000 - 0x328d4fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32927000 - 0x32930fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32a10000 - 0x32a3cfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32ac2000 - 0x32bd9ff9  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32c02000 - 0x32c06ffe  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32c1a000 - 0x32c24fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32c28000 - 0x32ee9fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x33331000 - 0x3338afff  IMAVCore armv7  <ce90304da959333d81a64171a6ac3ae8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x33393000 - 0x333dcff7  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x334ab000 - 0x334b3ffe  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x334be000 - 0x334d4ff3  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x334d5000 - 0x334f4fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x334f5000 - 0x334faffe  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x334fb000 - 0x33537fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x335f2000 - 0x335f7ffe  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x335f8000 - 0x335feff3  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33600000 - 0x33664fff  MessageUI armv7  <da7af4f9494b35558bf7892dfdb36ee3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x336f2000 - 0x3391fff7  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33941000 - 0x339ebfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33a0e000 - 0x33b53ffb  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33b56000 - 0x33bb9ffb  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x33cf0000 - 0x33cf7ff7  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33d12000 - 0x33d15ffc  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x33d16000 - 0x33d23ff7  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33d60000 - 0x33db1ff6  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33db2000 - 0x33dc4fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <50ea319aaeb7307e92719980dd4b2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x33e6b000 - 0x33e94fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x33ec0000 - 0x33ec0fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x33ec6000 - 0x33f6cfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x33f6d000 - 0x33f8dfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x33f91000 - 0x34069ff6  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x34077000 - 0x3407dfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x34090000 - 0x34098fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3409b000 - 0x3440affb  TextInput armv7  <8d7f24642c7634cc8e3a6e65f1dcd98e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3440b000 - 0x3441effe  AssistantServices armv7  <4a0843742f363a8885b8db13b44ae256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
0x344a7000 - 0x349ebff5  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x349ec000 - 0x34a02ff7  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x34b17000 - 0x34bddd63  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34c09000 - 0x34c0ffff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x34c10000 - 0x34c1aff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34c1c000 - 0x34c1cfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34c21000 - 0x34c69ffe  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34c6a000 - 0x34c71fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34c72000 - 0x34c75ffd  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x34d46000 - 0x34d97fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34db6000 - 0x34e7cfff  GLEngine armv7  <6617f2b4ee283469a5595129889ff049> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x34e7d000 - 0x34e96ff7  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x34e97000 - 0x34ed5fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34ed6000 - 0x34edaffd  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35041000 - 0x35057ffd  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35058000 - 0x3506eff5  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3506f000 - 0x35079ffb  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x3507f000 - 0x35521ff3  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35523000 - 0x35682ffe  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <06a0a1ee488030169bdfab11fc8d2c5c> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x35683000 - 0x356c6fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x356f6000 - 0x35705fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35706000 - 0x3570afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x357c6000 - 0x35f85ffb  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x35f86000 - 0x36056ffc  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36057000 - 0x360a3fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x360b3000 - 0x360f7ffb  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x360fb000 - 0x360fefff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x360ff000 - 0x36148ff0  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3615a000 - 0x36192ff3  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x36193000 - 0x362b8ff3  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3683e000 - 0x36915ff1  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36916000 - 0x36917fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36994000 - 0x36a0dfff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36a45000 - 0x36a84ff3  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x36a85000 - 0x36c42ff7  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36c43000 - 0x36c66ff7  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36c67000 - 0x36c9cff7  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36e8d000 - 0x37071ff7  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x37107000 - 0x3713bfff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x371a4000 - 0x371b0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x371bf000 - 0x3733dfff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x373ad000 - 0x373eafff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x37511000 - 0x37514fff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x37527000 - 0x375c0fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x375ed000 - 0x375f0ff8  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3767f000 - 0x37683ffc  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x37719000 - 0x3771affe  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3771b000 - 0x3775bffd  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37861000 - 0x37867ffe  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x378bc000 - 0x378c1fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <3c1cc3175c403ace8fcbd3826bd43807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
0x378c2000 - 0x378c5ffd  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x378c6000 - 0x378d2ff0  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x378d3000 - 0x3790eff7  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x37935000 - 0x37939ffc  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x379f0000 - 0x37a20ffe  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x37a21000 - 0x37a36fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x37a37000 - 0x37a3bfff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x37a3c000 - 0x37b85ff1  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37b86000 - 0x37ba9ffd  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x37bc7000 - 0x37bebff7  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x37bec000 - 0x37bf1ffe  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x37c5c000 - 0x37c68fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37c69000 - 0x37c78ff7  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x37d0e000 - 0x37dbcffb  Message armv7  <573d0118246d3d9d8aed17e7ee2faec7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
```

I am not understanding the issue given by the apple store as per the given log detail. Can anybody tell me where the problem occured?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Your app is called Password? I would start by trying to reproducing this error in a debugger. The exception EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION is pretty self explanatory. Your app tried to execute a bad instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but apple store crash report is saying that application is getting crashed in iPad 3 with iOS 5.1.1. It means in other versions & devices application is working properly. But I haven't iPad 3, then how can I test this issue to solve...?

I have only iPad 1 with iOS 5.1.1 to test application, in which application is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you google '**CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION**', you will get lots of hits. Many of the crash reports containing it are doing network activity - NSURLConnections etc.

One post mentioned that if you defined a category, but did not actually implement the method, you can get crashes like yours (the compiler does not enforce the existence of category methods).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but apple store crash report is saying that application is getting crashed in iPad 3 with iOS 5.1.1. It means in other versions & devices application is working properly. But I haven't iPad 3, then how can I test this issue to solve...?

Comment: I have only iPad 1 with iOS 5.1.1 to test application, in which application is working properly.

Comment: Are you including the -ObjC linker flag for any dependent libraries to enforce category methods being loaded?

Comment: You could go by the Apple store, see if they will let you test there in the store on a iPad 3. If not, buy one, take it home, test, fix your bug, then return it the next day.